# Can I override the submit button in an OOTB sharepoint page?

Tags: survey

I created a custom webpart which has an iframe inside of it. In this iframe I load the questions of a survey list. I did already using jQuery to style that page. I inject with jQuery some css in the page which is loaded in the iframe. In the survey question page there is a submit button. Is it possible to override this button? I would like to submit and finish it with a redirection to another page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PreSaveAction()` function to write your custom code before submitting the form.

You can do a `return false` to stop page from loading or else just do a Jquery redirect.

Comment: But I would like to do the submit first and then a redirect to some page. Is that possible?

Comment: Suppose you click submit button in page A and it gets you to page B. Add a js file to page B and write the redirect code like `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
function init(){
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}`